# Want to set the value of a textbox based on the value of a 2nd text box

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, textbox

I have a textbox which can be left blank or contain a date.  If the textbox has a date I want the 2nd textbox's value to be set to the value of a session variable.  I need this to happen before the update sql is performed on postback.

This is the code I have.  But the textbox is coming back as nothing.  Whether it has a value in it or not.

```
If IsPostBack Then
        Dim Dev_Doc_Date As TextBox
        Dev_Doc_Date = FindControl("Dev_Document_Date")

        If Not Dev_Doc_Date Is Nothing Then
            Dim Dev_Doc_Date_Value As String
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Dev_Doc_Date.Text) Then
                Dev_Doc_Date_Value = Dev_Doc_Date.Text
            Else
                Dev_Doc_Date_Value = String.Empty

            End If
        End If
End If
```

Comment: Are you sure your control is named 'Dev_Document_Date' and that it's not in a master page?  If it's in a master page, your control id may be prefixed with something like `ctrl00$...`.

Comment: Yes, I am sure it is named "Dev_Doc_Date" and it is not on a master page.  I know I am referencing it correctly as I would get an error when I called FindControl.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually Hoester, There was a typo.  I referenced the control as "Dev_Document_Date" versus "Dev_Doc_Date".  Which makes me rethink how the FindControl works.  Why didn't it error?  Still coming back as nothing however.

Answer (score 0):

I took a different route.  I passed the session variable using javascript.  If the length of the textbox (date) was equal to 8 (validation ensures that it is) then set the value of the 2nd textbox to the session variable.

```
function Uploader(field, e)
{
    var inputName = field.name;
    var len = document.getElementById(inputName).value.length;

    if (len == 8)
    {
        window.document.form1.FormView1$Dev_Doc_Updater.value = "<%= Session("PIN") %>";
    }   
}
```